# How to color VIM ":!{cmd}" output?

Tags: neovim, shell, color

I'm trying to get the same setup as the guy in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etosV2IWBF0&t=27m22s) video, so that when `:!pytest %` gets called, the output is colored.

I've tried with various vanilla colorschemes, with no luck...

I'm using Neovim, with TERM=st-256color (tried setting to xterm-256), but got nowhere... :(

EDIT:
[image: Output in terminal]

[image: Output in NVIM]

Comment: Hi, welcome! Is the output different if you run pytest in your terminal directly? If not, this is not about vim, but most likely about your terminal itself, or your command.

Comment: Hi @Biggybi, thank you for the warm welcome! I've added pictures showcasing the issue.

Comment: The video is on Vim, not Neovim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The video shows Vim, not Neovim. In Neovim the output of "bang" is not colorized.

If you like long stories you can read [this](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496) and [this](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/137#issuecomment-77713710) and so on.

TL;DR they think it's not a big deal, but fixing "bang" may be too hard, so just use `:terminal` instead.

Comment: Love long stories! Thank you so much Matt!

Comment: Hi Matt, I've figured how to solve the issue. Would you consider adding the following to your answer?
From: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/neovim-how-to-close-the-terminal-buffer-by-just-pressing-enter

Adding `autocmd TermOpen * startinsert` to your .vimrc (or init.vim for NVIM users), makes terminal behave the same as "bang", such that it will exit on <CR>

Comment: That, combined with your answer (using :terminal), fixed it for me without "behaviour" changes (except some tweaking to split instead of open a full buffer)

Comment: @eltbus This is rather your personal preference. In general, you don't have to enter insert mode in order to close terminal. Just press `ZZ` or such, just like any normal buffer. On split, something like `:split +term` will do in Neovim.

Comment: But ":terminal"  by itself behaves differently than "bang" output wise. Still, I have to agree. It's a personal choice.